# #1305 - FUNCTION [table_name].ADD_DATE does not exist

Tags: mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin

I want to add 1 year to a datetime-type column in every single row in a table.and I use below statement

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name ]=ADD_DATE(yyyy,1,[column_name ])
```

but i got this error message in phpmyadmin '#1305 - FUNCTION [table_name].ADD_DATE does not exist '
also I tried to use :

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name ]=ADD_DATE(yy,1,[column_name ]),
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name ]=ADD_DATE(YEAR,1,[column_name ]),
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name ]=DATEADD(yyyy,1,[column_name ]),
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name ]=DATEADD(yy,1,[column_name ]),
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name ]=DATEADD(YEAR,1,[column_name ])
```

But I got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because no function named as `add_date`. Try this instead:

```
 UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name ]=ADDDATE([column_name ], INTERVAL 1 YEAR );
```

`date_add` also can be used. These two functions are just synonym.

[SEE MANUAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)